# I want to fetch the data from Api using Retrofit in android with java and set on Spinner

Tags: java, android, retrofit

This is my API url

```
@GET("/payment/fetch/board/{username}")
Call<List<BoardResponse>>fetchBoardList(String username);
```

And This is my Retrofit to call url

```
Call<List<BoardResponse>>call=RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi().fetchBoardList(username);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BoardResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<BoardResponse>> call, @NonNull Response<List<BoardResponse>> response) {
               if(response.isSuccessful()){
                   if(response.body() != null){
                     String jsonResponse=response.body().toString();
                       try {
                           ArrayList<BoardResponse>boardArray = new ArrayList<>();
                           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                           JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                           for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                           BoardResponse spinnerModel = new BoardResponse();
                           JSONObject dataObj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                           spinnerModel.setBoard(dataObj.getString("board"));
                           spinnerModel.setBoardID(dataObj.getInt("boardID"));
                           spinnerModel.setUsername(dataObj.getString("username"));

                           boardArray.add(spinnerModel);

                       }

                       for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.size(); i++){
                           boardList.add(boardArray.get(i).getBoard().toString());
                       }
                       ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PaymentEntryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,boardList);
                       spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                       Spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       throw new RuntimeException(e);
                   }

               }
           }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<BoardResponse>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.hpl.raja.boardpayment/com.hpl.raja.boardpayment.PaymentEntryActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found.
> (parameter #1)
> for method MyApi.fetchBoardList

so please help me Thanks

I have error that found

Answer (score 0):

After Adding @path  I solved my problem like this

@GET("/payment/fetch/board/{username}")
Call<List>fetchBoardList(@Path("username") String username);

Comment: And some changes in Calling retrofit like JsonArray remove and Simply get the data from response in array

Answer (score 0):

in the retrofit API interface, you should add @Path before username parameter  like this

```
@GET("/payment/fetch/board/{username}")
Call<List<BoardResponse>>fetchBoardList(@Path("username") String username);
```